# Create a reference to Locator in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, service-locator

I have a WPF Custom Control Library with MVVM Libraries.

In Dictionary I have:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary2"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    d1p1:Ignorable="d"
                    xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                        d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

And in Window.xaml I try to use that Locator:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFCustomeControlLibrary.Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window" Height="300" Width="300"
        DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

But it still says 'The resource 'Locator' could not be resolved'.

Locator is my ViewModelLocator where my MainViewModel is defined.

Comment: Why are you putting it in a resource dictionary in the first place?

Comment: @ThomasV becouse there is no other option in a WPF Custom Control Library.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The resource cannot be defined in the window since it needs to be resolved *before* the `DataContext` is set.

The other option would be to set the `DataContext` of the `Grid` instead of the `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFCustomeControlLibrary.Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: There is no App.xaml in a WPF Custom Control Library.

Comment: No. That's why you should add it to the App.xaml of the actual application...or use another approach as I suggested in the answer.

Comment: I'm thinking to put every module just in the main application.

Comment: Is that a question? How is it related to your original one?

Comment: No its not a question, but it seems impossible to split up a wpf mvvm project into different assemblies.

Comment: Well, at least if you use a view model locator like that and expect the window to work without the locator being defined globally somewhere.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if your original issue has been solved.